# Why does outside form button not work in iPhone browser?

Tags: iphone, ajax, forms, label, submit

I have tried to make the submit button outside with this code it works on normal browser as firefox. Is there somebody who got a good solution for this?

```
<label for="submit-form" id="upload_yes_cursor" onClick="parent.location='edit_note.php'">Yes</label>



<div id="edit_note_box_wrapper"> 
<div id="edit_note_box_inner">
<form action="insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="this.color.value =  document.form2.color.value; this.color.value = document.form2.color.value;" name="form1">
      <input type="text" class="edit_note_title" placeholder="Title" name="title">  
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="textarea"></label>
      <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Description" data-role="none"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div id="check">
      <input type="hidden" name="color"> 
      </div>


      <div id="submit_hidden">
      <input type="submit" id="submit-form"/>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your using Javascript in your button submition. Many mobile browsers are not able to use javascript. So, yeah xD

Comment: Almost all modern mobile browsers support Javascript.